# Regular Expression Explanation [\w-\.]

Tags: regex

What does this RegExp mean please?

```
[\w-\.]
```

I know the `\w` stands for word characters and could alternatively be written as:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]
```

I know the `\.` means that the point will be treated as an ordinary character.

The only thing I don't really know is the hyphen character. Is this used as a Range Operator here or just the hyphen character in e.g. "fine-tune"?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/372239

Comment: FYI there's no need to escape the dot `.` in a character class, `[\w-.]` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hyphen** here is just the hyphen character.

**Hyphen is treated as a range operator only when it is between two other characters.**

Answer (score 0):

Hyphen is normal character here, so it works as `[a-zA-z0-9_-\.]` (number, letters, and these three characters: `-_.`).

Comment: Be careful, in `[a-zA-z0-9_-.]` the `-` *would* be interpreted as a range - and cause an error since `_` ascii value is greater than `.`. I'm guessing you meant `[a-zA-z0-9_.-]` ?